# Error in my derivation of $\binom{2n-1}{n}$ as number of partitions of $n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, integer-partitions

Does a formula for the number of partitions of an integer exist? Given
that this sequence is in the OEIS (https://oeis.org/A000041) I would guess not.

However I have an intuitive way of counting them, which apparently must be wrong.

For any integer n, we can write the integer as an equation
$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = n$ where $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are integers.
For example we could have $x_1=n-1, x_2=1, x_3=...=x_n=0$, or $x_1=n-3, x_2=1, x_3=2, 
x_4=...=x_n=0$, or $x_1=n, x_2=...=x_n=0$, and so on.

The number of solutions to this equation can be determined with stars and bars
method of combinatorics to be $2n-1 \choose n$, which equals $\frac{(2n-1)!}{n! (n-1)!}$. Would this
not serve as a general formula for the number of partitions of the integer $n$?

Comment: Well, does that match the sequence you linked to?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the helpful comment. I already said that I know I'm wrong, I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: So, look at the first case in which your formula differs from the sequence  (which happens for very small $n$) and go through the combinations counted by Stars and Bars.  The problem will become clear quickly.

Comment: Stars and bars doesn't work here because the $x_i$s aren't "different". I.e, letting $x_1=2$ and $x_2=2$ you can't distinguish between writing $4$ as $x_1+x_2$ or $x_2+x_1$.

Comment: In counting partitions, there is the implicit assumption that $x_1\ge x_2\ge\cdots\ge x_n$, which you don't have in "stars and bars".

Comment: @K.defaoite I see, thank you! I wonder if there's a way to control for that, similar to how we control for repeated occurrences of elements in permutations of words by dividing by a factorial. Though I realize I'm pursuing a dead end at this point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a closed formula for the partitions of an integer, even though Ramanujan created a formula that approximates the result:

$$p(n) \sim \frac{\exp\left(\pi \sqrt{\frac{3n}{2}} \right)}{4n\sqrt{3}} $$

But this approximation only works when n is very large. To calculate the partitions of an integer, computations often rely on the partitions of the previous integers. This [interactive document](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Euler_partition_function.svg) that you can find on the [Wikipedia page of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) is the one that helped me understand better how we compute partitions.